# Display Modal Dialog Box with ActiveX

Tags: activex, modal-dialog

I'd like to create an ActiveX browser plugin that displays a modal dialog box to the user...but how do I do that? If you know of some basic tutorial out there that does exactly this it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can display modal dialog as usual use [DialogBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#modal_box).

Only ActiveX control should call method [IOleInPlaceFrame::EnableModeless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before and after show dialog. Pointer to the IOleInPlaceFrame you can get from your container via [IOleInPlaceSite::GetWindowContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694366%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreModalDialog()` and `PostModalDialog()`