# Support modal and modeless dialogs in ActiveX controls

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, activex, ole

I want to create an ActiveX control supporting modal and modeless dialogs, which can be used in multiple IE9~IE11 tab pages at the same time. It means a pop-up of dialog box by the ActiveX control within current IE tab page won't prevent us from switching to other IE tab pages and these dialogs only appear in current IE tab page. First I created an ATL Dynamic-link library (DLL) application named as AtlActiveX using ATL/C++ by Visual Studio 2010. Then add an ActiveX control named as AtlActiveXCtl, specifying Allow merging of proxy/stub code and IObjectWithSite (IE object support) options. And then add a dialog resource named as IDD_DIALOG1. If not mentioned here, other options are left as default. Since windows/dialogs need to be supported, the member variable m_bWindowOnly has to be assigned in CAtlActiveXCtl constructor. After that add a message handler for WM_CREATE message, displaying dialog boxes in OnCreate function. The full code of AtlActiveXCtl.h is attached below.

I referred to another question [Display Modal Dialog Box with ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588036/display-modal-dialog-box-with-activex) on StackOverflow. Three pop-up dialogs are tested in OnCreate() function.

```
#pragma once
#include "resource.h"
#include <atlctl.h>
#include "AtlActiveX_i.h"

using namespace ATL;

// Modeless dialog
class CModelessDialog : public CDialogImpl<CModelessDialog>
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CModelessDialog)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CLOSE, OnClose)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL &)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnClose(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL &)
    {
        DestroyWindow();
        return 0;
    }
};

// CAtlActiveXCtl
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CAtlActiveXCtl :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IAtlActiveXCtl, &IID_IAtlActiveXCtl, &LIBID_AtlActiveXLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IOleControlImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public IOleObjectImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public IOleInPlaceActiveObjectImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public IViewObjectExImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public IOleInPlaceObjectWindowlessImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public IQuickActivateImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public IDataObjectImpl<CAtlActiveXCtl>,
    public IProvideClassInfo2Impl<&CLSID_AtlActiveXCtl, NULL, &LIBID_AtlActiveXLib>,
    public CComCoClass<CAtlActiveXCtl, &CLSID_AtlActiveXCtl>,
    public CComControl<CAtlActiveXCtl>
{
public:
    CAtlActiveXCtl()
    {
        m_bWindowOnly = 1;
    }

DECLARE_OLEMISC_STATUS(OLEMISC_RECOMPOSEONRESIZE |
    OLEMISC_CANTLINKINSIDE |
    OLEMISC_INSIDEOUT |
    OLEMISC_ACTIVATEWHENVISIBLE |
    OLEMISC_SETCLIENTSITEFIRST
)

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_ATLACTIVEXCTL)

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CAtlActiveXCtl)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IAtlActiveXCtl)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IViewObjectEx)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IViewObject2)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IViewObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleInPlaceObjectWindowless)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleInPlaceObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY2(IOleWindow, IOleInPlaceObjectWindowless)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleInPlaceActiveObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleControl)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IQuickActivate)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDataObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo2)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectWithSite)
END_COM_MAP()

BEGIN_PROP_MAP(CAtlActiveXCtl)
    PROP_DATA_ENTRY("_cx", m_sizeExtent.cx, VT_UI4)
    PROP_DATA_ENTRY("_cy", m_sizeExtent.cy, VT_UI4)
    // Example entries
    // PROP_ENTRY_TYPE("Property Name", dispid, clsid, vtType)
    // PROP_PAGE(CLSID_StockColorPage)
END_PROP_MAP()

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CAtlActiveXCtl)
    CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CComControl<CAtlActiveXCtl>)
    DEFAULT_REFLECTION_HANDLER()
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate)
END_MSG_MAP()
// Handler prototypes:
//  LRESULT MessageHandler(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled);
//  LRESULT CommandHandler(WORD wNotifyCode, WORD wID, HWND hWndCtl, BOOL& bHandled);
//  LRESULT NotifyHandler(int idCtrl, LPNMHDR pnmh, BOOL& bHandled);

// ISupportsErrorInfo
    STDMETHOD(InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo)(REFIID riid)
    {
        static const IID* const arr[] =
        {
            &IID_IAtlActiveXCtl,
        };

        for (int i=0; i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
        {
            if (InlineIsEqualGUID(*arr[i], riid))
                return S_OK;
        }
        return S_FALSE;
    }

// IViewObjectEx
    DECLARE_VIEW_STATUS(VIEWSTATUS_SOLIDBKGND | VIEWSTATUS_OPAQUE)

// IAtlActiveXCtl
public:
    LRESULT OnCreate(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        IOleInPlaceFrame *pOleInPlaceFrame = NULL;
        IOleInPlaceUIWindow *pOleInPlaceUIwindow = NULL;
        IOleInPlaceSite *pOleInPlaceSite = NULL;

        OLEINPLACEFRAMEINFO oleInPlaceFrameInfo;
        oleInPlaceFrameInfo.cb = sizeof(oleInPlaceFrameInfo);
        HRESULT hr = m_spClientSite->QueryInterface(IID_IOleInPlaceSite, (LPVOID *)&pOleInPlaceSite);
        if (hr != S_OK)
            return S_OK;

        RECT rc1, rc2;
        hr = pOleInPlaceSite->GetWindowContext(&pOleInPlaceFrame, &pOleInPlaceUIwindow, &rc1, &rc2, &oleInPlaceFrameInfo);
        {
            HWND hWndTop = NULL;
            pOleInPlaceSite->GetWindow(&hWndTop);

            pOleInPlaceFrame->EnableModeless(TRUE);
            ::EnableWindow(hWndTop, FALSE);

            //[1] Message box, cannot switch tab page
            MessageBox(L"Hello, world!", L"MSG", MB_OK);

            //[2] Modal dialog, cannot switch tab page
            CSimpleDialog<IDD_DIALOG1> dlg;
            dlg.DoModal(hWndTop);

            //[3] Modeless dialog, can switch tab page, but always stays on top of IE browser
            CModelessDialog *pDlg = new CModelessDialog;
            pDlg->Create(hWndTop);
            pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);

            pOleInPlaceFrame->EnableModeless(FALSE);
            ::EnableWindow(hWndTop, TRUE);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    HRESULT OnDraw(ATL_DRAWINFO& di)
    {
        RECT& rc = *(RECT*)di.prcBounds;

        // Set Clip region to the rectangle specified by di.prcBounds
        HRGN hRgnOld = NULL;
        if (GetClipRgn(di.hdcDraw, hRgnOld) != 1)
            hRgnOld = NULL;

        bool bSelectOldRgn = false;
        HRGN hRgnNew = CreateRectRgn(rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
        if (hRgnNew != NULL)
            bSelectOldRgn = (SelectClipRgn(di.hdcDraw, hRgnNew) != ERROR);

        Rectangle(di.hdcDraw, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
        SetTextAlign(di.hdcDraw, TA_CENTER|TA_BASELINE);
        LPCTSTR pszText = _T("AtlActiveXCtl");
        TextOut(di.hdcDraw,
            (rc.left + rc.right) / 2,
            (rc.top + rc.bottom) / 2,
            pszText,
            lstrlen(pszText));

        if (bSelectOldRgn)
            SelectClipRgn(di.hdcDraw, hRgnOld);

        return S_OK;
    }

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
    }
};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(AtlActiveXCtl), CAtlActiveXCtl)
```

Modal and modeless dialogs need to be supported in ActiveX controls within IE11 tab pages just like in plain Win32 GUI applications. Can anyone kindly help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please inform us what problem you are facing from the above posted code? Did you get any error? If yes than try to provide an information about it. We will try to looks in to it and try to provide you suggestions for that.

Comment: The first problem is when a modal dialog pop ups by this ActiveX control, we can't switch to other IE tab pages. The other one is when a modeless dialog pop ups, we can switch IE tab page, but it always stays on top of IE browser before closing it.

Comment: I will try to involve any senior engineer to look in to this issue. They will try to provide you further suggestions. It may take some time to get the response from them due to weekend holidays. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you for offering help. For me, IE plugin development is not easy since it's lack of documentation and examples.

Comment: Can you please try to change this registry value to o and again try to make a test to see the result?   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Type: REG_DWORD

Name: HangRecovery

Value: 0